# phpエラーログのカスタマイズ

Tags: php, apache

お世話になります。
phpのエラーログのカスタマイズについて質問です。

```
[Fri May 22 18:36:20 2015] [error] [client 123.456.678.000] ERROR_MESSAGE
```

デフォルトではこのような感じでロギングされているのですが、このIPアドレス部分が
プロキシというかLBを通る通信をしているので、誰がアクセスしても同じIPアドレスになってしまいます。
Apacheの方では、

```
LogFormat "%{X-Cluster-Client-Ip}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

という設定にすることで接続元のIPをX-Cluster-Client-Ipから取得できます。
phpのエラーログの場合はどのように設定するのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache httpd 2.2 までは ErrorLog の書式は変更できないようです。
Apache httpd 2.4 では [ErrorLogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#errorlogformat) で変更できます。

Comment: Taichi Yanagiyaさん、ありがとうございます。
なるほど、2.2じゃ無理なんですね。
アクセスログの方と比較して分析するしかないようです。
ありがとうございました。